# webdriver tests failing in IE9

Tags: extjs, internet-explorer-9, webdriver

I am running webdriver tests to test an web application with extjs elements (the elements have static test identifiers to negate the test ids from changing) written in Java and running with junit 4 on ie9.  Tests will pass when run individually.  However, when running tests on a remote machine,tests appear to fail randomly.  Usually the tests time out because elements cannot we found.  I have allowed sufficient time for elements to be loaded and I have avoided using sleep conditions in my tests.  Any advice for running tests under ie9 would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain how did you implement synchronization?

Comment: Hi Nilesh Im quite new to this and not sure if I fully understand what you are asking.  I have a number of different wait methods which will wait for elements to be present or for an element count to equal a certain number.  I have avoided sleeps as much as possible.  The tests are run after a nightly build under junit 4 via Jenkins.  Please can you elaborate on the information you are looking for and I will be glad to explain further.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Peter - if you can post the code for one of the tests that is failing it might help folks provide you a better answer. Even better if you can post your test code along with a snippet of the page DOM it is working against that would help.